# Android: show/hide a view using an animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I've been looking through many google results / questions on here to determine how to show/hide a view via a vertical animation, but I can't seem to find one that's exactly right or not too vague.

I have a layout (undo bar) that's below another layout and above multiple other widgets; this undo bar should vertically slide open and slide closed, depending on the circumstances.

Currently all I do right now is set the view to be visible or gone.

Answer (score 68):

Set the attribute 
    `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`
inside the parent layout .

Put the view in a layout if its not and set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` for that layout.

NOTE: This works only from API Level 11+ (Android 3.0)

Answer (score 19):

I created an extension for `RelativeLayout` that shows/hides Layouts with animations.
It can extend any kind of `View` to gain these features.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class AnimatingRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
    Context context;
    Animation inAnimation;
    Animation outAnimation;

    public AnimatingRelativeLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initAnimations();

    }

    public AnimatingRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initAnimations();
    }

    public AnimatingRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        initAnimations();
    }

    private void initAnimations()
    {
        inAnimation = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.in_animation);
        outAnimation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.out_animation);
    }

    public void show()
    {
        if (isVisible()) return;
        show(true);
    }

    public void show(boolean withAnimation)
    {
        if (withAnimation) this.startAnimation(inAnimation);
        this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide()
    {
        if (!isVisible()) return;
        hide(true);
    }

    public void hide(boolean withAnimation)
    {
        if (withAnimation) this.startAnimation(outAnimation);
        this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public boolean isVisible()
    {
        return (this.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void overrideDefaultInAnimation(Animation inAnimation)
    {
        this.inAnimation = inAnimation;
    }

    public void overrideDefaultOutAnimation(Animation outAnimation)
    {
        this.outAnimation = outAnimation;
    }
}
```

You can override the original `Animation`s using `overrideDefaultInAnimation` and `overrideDefaultOutAnimation`

My original Animations were fadeIn/Out, I am adding XML animation files for Translating in/out of the screen (Translate to top and from top)

in_animation.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

out_animation.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

Answer (score 15):

This can reasonably be achieved in a single line statement in API 12 and above. Below is an example where `v` is the view you wish to animate;

```
v.animate().translationXBy(-1000).start();
```

This will slide the `View` in question off to the left by 1000px. To slide the view back onto the UI we can simply do the following.

```
v.animate().translationXBy(1000).start();
```

I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 11):

If you only want to animate the height of a view (from say 0 to a certain number) you could implement your own animation:

```
final View v = getTheViewToAnimateHere();
Animation anim=new Animation(){
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        // Do relevant calculations here using the interpolatedTime that runs from 0 to 1
        v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int)(30*interpolatedTime)));
    }};
anim.setDuration(500);
v.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 7):

I have used this two function to hide and show view with transition animation smoothly.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void expand(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight, final int position) {

        int prevHeight = v.getHeight();

        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.start();
        valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                v.clearAnimation();
            }
        });

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void collapse(final View v, int duration, int targetHeight, final int position) {
        if (position == (data.size() - 1)) {
            return;
        }
        int prevHeight = v.getHeight();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevHeight, targetHeight);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.start();
        valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                animBoolArray.put(position, false);
                v.clearAnimation();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) class, which creates the animation for position changes. Try reading this for help - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

Update: Here's the example for this. If you have the height of your view as 50 and in the hide mode you want to show only 10 px. The sample code would be -

```
TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-40,0);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
view.setAnimation(anim);
```

PS: There are lot's or other methods there to help you use the animation according to your need. Also have a look at the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams if you want to completely customize the code, however using the TranslateAnimation is easier to use.

**EDIT:-Complex version using LayoutParams**

```
RelativeLayout relParam=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParam(RelativeLayout.LayoutParam.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParam.WRAP_CONTENT); //you can give hard coded width and height here in (width,height) format.
relParam.topMargin=-50; //any number that work.Set it to 0, when you want to show it.
view.setLayoutParams(relparam);
```

This example code assumes you are putting your view in RelativeLayout, if not change the name of Layout, however other layout might not work. If you want to give an animation effect on them, reduce or increase the topMargin slowly. You can consider using Thread.sleep() there too.

Comment: ScaleAnimation doesn't change position, it scales the view... You are confusing with TranslateAnimation.

Comment: I guess you got what you need, and if not here is a sample code - TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(fromX,toX,fromY,toY); view.setAnimation(anim);

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
view.animate()
    .translationY(0)
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all get the height of the view yo want to saw and make a boolean to save if the view is showing:

```
int heigth=0;
boolean showing=false;
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        proDetailsLL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // gets called after layout has been done but before display
                // so we can get the height then hide the view

                proHeight = proDetailsLL.getHeight(); // Ahaha!  Gotcha

                proDetailsLL.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                proDetailsLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
            }
        });
```

Then call the method for showing hide the view, and change the value of the boolean:

```
slideInOutAnimation(showing, heigth, layout);
proShowing = !proShowing;
```

The method:

```
/**
     * Method to slide in out the layout
     * 
     * @param isShowing
     *            if the layout is showing
     * @param height
     *            the height to slide
     * @param slideLL
     *            the container to show
     */
private void slideInOutAnimation(boolean isShowing, int height, final LinearLayout slideLL, final ImageView arroIV) {

        if (!isShowing) {
        Animation animIn = new Animation() {
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        // Do relevant calculations here using the interpolatedTime that runs from 0 to 1
        slideLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (heigth * interpolatedTime)));

                }
            };
            animIn.setDuration(500);
            slideLL.startAnimation(animIn);
        } else {

            Animation animOut = new Animation() {
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
                    // Do relevant calculations here using the interpolatedTime that runs from 0 to 1


                        slideLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                (int) (heigth * (1 - interpolatedTime))));

                }
            };
            animOut.setDuration(500);
            slideLL.startAnimation(animOut);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewAnimator:

In XML:

```
  <ViewAnimator
    android:id="@+id/animator_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_down_text"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_up_text">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_message_authentication"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="message_error_authentication" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_message_authentication_connection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="message_error_authentication_connection" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_message_authentication_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="message_error_authentication_field_empty" />

</ViewAnimator>
```

Functions:

```
public void show(int viewId) {
    ViewAnimator animator = (ViewAnimator) findView(animatorId);
    View view = findViewById(viewId);

    if (animator.getDisplayedChild() != animator.indexOfChild(view)) {
        animator.setDisplayedChild(animator.indexOfChild(view));
     }
 }


 private void showAuthenticationConnectionFailureMessage() {
    show(R.id.text_message_authentication_connection);
}
```